# Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/puppies' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: reactjs, laravel, cors

I want to get my list in my Reacjs app from the backend with Laravel. When I call Api in Reactjs component and it gives me this error message

**Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/puppies' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

I create a middleware in my backend Laravel CORS

**cors middleware**

```
<?PHP
  namespace App\Http\Middleware;
  use Closure;
  class Cors
  {
  /**
  * Handle an incoming request.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @param  \Closure  $next
  * @return mixed
  */
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    return $next($request)
     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "PUT, POST, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS")
     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Accept,Authorization,Content-Type");
  }
 }
```

**my API route**

```
Route::apiResource('puppies', 'Api\PuppiesController');
```

**frontend code**

**my card js API**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect}  from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {getPuppies} from "./apiCore";

const Card = () => {
const [allPets, setAllPets] = useState([]);

const loadAllPets = () => {
    getPuppies().then(data => {
        if(data.error){
            console.log(data.error)
        } else{
            setAllPets(data)
        }
    });
};

useEffect(() =>{
    loadAllPets();
}, [])

return(
    <div>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12">
                {/* <div className="listing-block">
                    <div className="listing-image">
                        <img src="img/listing.jpg" alt="safari"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="listing-content">
                        <div className="tag ondeposite">ON Deposite</div>
                        <h3>Golden Retriver</h3>
                        <h4>Poodele, 4 Weeks</h4>
                        <Link to="/description" className="boxed-btn3">View Puppy</Link>
                    </div>
                </div> */}
                {JSON.stringify(allPets)}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   )
   }
   export default Card;
```

**API**

```
import {API} from "../config";
export const getPuppies = () =>{
const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/puppies"
return fetch(url, {
  method: "GET",
})
.then(response =>{
 return response.json();      
})
.catch(err =>{
  console.log(err);
  });
 };
```

For more clear please find attached an image.
Please help
Thanks in Advance.
[image]

Comment: what is your backend code for getting pippies ?

Comment: my backend in Laravel using Laravel resource collection

Comment: Any updates? or solution to post?

Comment: yes working fine now.........I do this by using middleware

Answer (score -2):

I think you can install this extension in your browser :

```
Extension : Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```